# info - Generating static pages (13/13)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

```
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    /_error: /404
    /_error: /500
    /aid_application
    /consumer_application
    /consumer_application/[id]
    /consumer_application/application
    /consumer_application/change_password
    /nursing_assessment/[id]
    /patient_emergency/[id]
    /plan_of_care/[id]
    /receiver
    /signin
```

I tried many solutions available on google, also i inspected my code multiple times but was not able to debug the issue. It was working fine earlier, but after adding a feature, it stopped working. I am getting this error on building nextjs app, although app is running fine if i run yarn dev